# A product topology where we allow countably many open sets

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Let $\{X_{\alpha}\}$ be an uncountable collection of topological spaces indexed by the set $J$. For the space $\prod_{\alpha}X_{\alpha}$, consider the topology $\tau$ generated by the basis

$$\mathcal{B}=\left\{\left(\prod_{\alpha\in S}U_{\alpha}\right)\times\left(\prod_{\beta\notin S}X_{\beta}\right): U_{\alpha}\text{ open in }X_{\alpha},S\subseteq J\right\}.$$

If $S$ is arbitrary, then $\tau$ is the box topology. If $S$ is finite, then $\tau$ is the product topology. What if we allow $S$ to be countable? Has this topology been studied at all? Does it have a use somewhere?

Comment: I've search related terms in Google. If my searching is correct, your concept is called the $\Sigma$-product. [A blog of Dan Ma](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/) introduces many facts about the $\Sigma$-product.

Comment: @HanulJeon Unless I'm mistaken, it looks like Dan Ma defines a $\Sigma$-product as a particular subspace of $X= \prod X_{\alpha}$ equipped with the subspace topology, not giving $X$ itself a separate topology.

Comment: @HanulJeon indeed, its not a $\Sigma$-product.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.3665.pdf) may help.

Comment: This is the $G_\delta$-topology of the product space, isn't it? For examples, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.04871v1 , https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07991v1

Comment: @ChrisCulter: only if the $X_\alpha$ already have a $G_\delta$ topology ("P spaces")

Comment: @Dap Whoops, you're right, thanks for the correction!